# Will a long % int will always fit into an int

Tags: java

Can anyone confirm if this is true?

Java will turn a `long` % `int` into a `long` value.  However it can never be greater than the modulus to it is always safe to cast it to an `int`.

```
long a = 
int b =
int c = (int) (a % b); // cast is always safe.
```

Similarly a `long` % `short` will always be safe to cast to a `short`.

If true, does any one know why Java has a longer type for `%` than needed?

Additionally, there is a similar case for `long` & `int` (if you ignore sign extension)

Comment: What is the value of b is 1 and the variable a has really long value, then the result would not fit into the int.

Comment: @Cybernate, that's true for division, not for remainder. If `b` is `1`, then `a % b` is _always_ `0`.

Comment: @Cybernate, `x % 1` is always `0` and fits inside and `int` ;)

Comment: @Hennin: My bad..overlooked and assumed % as / :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For most (if not all) arithmetic operations, Java will assume you want the maximum defined precision. Imagine if you did this:

```
long a = ...;
int b = ...;

long c = a % b + Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

If Java automatically down-casted `a % b` to an `int`, then the above code would cause an `int` overflow rather than setting `c` to a perfectly reasonable `long` value.

This is the same reason that performing operations with a `double` and an `int` will produce a `double`. It's much safer to up-cast the least-accurate value to a more accurate one. Then if the programmer knows more than the compiler and wants to down-cast, he can do it explicitly.

### Update

Also, after thinking more about this, I'm guessing most CPU architectures don't have operations that combine 32-bit and 64-bit values. So the 32-bit value would need to be promoted to a 64-bit value just to use it as an argument to the CPU's mod operation, and the result of that operation would be a 64-bit value natively. A down-cast to an `int` would add an operation, which has performance implications. Combining that fact with the idea that you might actually want to keep a `long` value for other operations (as I mention above), it really wouldn't make sense to force the result into an `int` unless the developer explicitly wants it to be one.

Comment: +1: What happens to a longer expression is the best explanation so far for why this is done.

Comment: +1 Good catch! One nit: `b` should be an `int` in your code snippet to match the question, but your point still holds.

Answer (score 11):

It is always safe! (Math agrees with me.)

The result of a mod operation is always less than the divisor.  Since the result of a mod operation is essentially the remainder after performing integer division, you will never have a remainder larger than the divisor.

I suspect the reason for having the operation return a `long` is because the divisor gets expanded to a `long` before the operation takes place.  This makes a `long` result possible. (*note* even though the variable is expanded in memory, its value will not change.  An expanded `int` will never be larger than an `int` can hold.)

Comment: Where's the answer for *"does any one know why Java has a longer type for % than needed?"*

Comment: @Balus, oops.  I missed that part of the question.

Comment: "This makes a long result possible." would mean its not always safe??

Comment: @Peter, no.  Expanding an `int` to a `long` simply makes it take more memory.  It will not actually grow the value.  (Same goes for `short` or `byte`.)

Comment: So are you saying a result which needs a long is possible or not?

Comment: @Peter, I'm sorry I'm not begin clear.  When performing mod by `int`, the result will always fit inside of an `int`.  So, the cast is always safe.

Answer (score 4):

As Marc B alluded to, Java will promote `b` to a `long` before actually doing the `%` operation. This promotion applies to all the arithmetic operations, even `<<` and `>>` I believe.

In other words, if you have a binary operation and the two arguments don't have the same type, the smaller one will be promoted so that both sides will have the same type.

Comment: Yes, but why? It doesn't appear to need to ever.

Comment: I suspect its to keep things simple and follow the rule you mention even if its not ideal.

Comment: The bitshift operators are special in that the two operands are promoted separately. This has the practical effect that e.g. `1 << 2L` is an int, not a long. (It makes no difference as long as the shift amount is an int or shorter).

Answer (score 4):

This is a late party chime-in but the reason is pretty simple:

The bytecode operands do need explicit  casts (`L2I`) and longs need 2 stack positions compared to 1 for int, char, short, byte [casting from byte to int doesn't need a bytecode instruction]. After the mod operation the result takes 2 positions on the top of stack.

*edit:* Also, I forgot to mention Java doesn't have division/remainder of 64b/32b. There are only 64->64bit operations, i.e. `LDIV` and `LREM`.

Comment: This question is; will the top 32-bits just contain the sign of the lower 32-bits, making it redundant?

Comment: @Peter, sure even x86's IDIV 64b/32b returns the quotient and the remainder in EAX/EDX (both are 32bit registers). I mean is quite clear diving by n bits sized divisor the result can be up to n bits size. (Added an edit too)

Answer (score 1):

> does any one know why Java has a longer type for % than needed?

I don't know for sure. Maybe to make it work exactly the same way as the other multiplicative operators: `*` and `\`. In the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17) `The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its operands.` Adding an exception to `long % int` would be confusing.